# jQuery autocomplet action

Tags: jquery, form-submit, jquery-autocomplete

I implement an autocomplet function in a database; the search area is an 'input' attached to a form and I want that when a choice is made in the list, the action of the form is triggered automatically.
Actually, I've got to select my choice and validate this form.

I tried to detect the change into the field:

```
  $("#tags").change(function() {
      $( "#search_form" ).submit();
    });
```

but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Change only fires when blur() happens (the element loses focus). Try using keydown/keypress/etc.

Comment: Thanks ! that was the way

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select: function(event, ui) {             
                    $("#search_form").submit(); 
                    }
    });
```

That works